# Why does deduction fail for std::set in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, set, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I have a `std::set` which allows deduction from an iterator range.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() 
{
   std::set s1 = {1,2,3,4}; 
   std::set s2(s1.begin(), s1.end());
}
```

The above program [failed to compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6piqFb9VsZ6E466u) in GCC.

Why does deduction fail for `std::set` here?

Comment: @Kevin (and Ron) C++17 added class template argument deduction. The question is why it isn't implemented for the iterators constructor.

Comment: @Ron it is, in the tags :)

Comment: According to the [GCC feature matrix](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) _Template argument deduction for class templates_ should be in version 7.

Comment: @YSC the matrix shows the core feature. It works in gcc7 (s1 initialisation compiles)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just take the current GCC version (8.0.0 at this time) and it will build. The template deduction guide for `std::set` just doesn't seem to be implemented in the older GCC version's stdlib.

Answer (score 1):

#### Deduction guides for the iterators constructors of `std::set` was only recently added to gcc HEAD.

According to `gcc-mirror/gcc` at GitHub, the deduction guides for `std::set`'s iterators constructor(s) was [added and merged to libstdc++-v3 less than two weeks ago](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/aa9edc021f49a47c1e512a10df3b587b8182e5aa#diff-2ad5e72f58ce2a827eeb1e6488be5ec6),

> (Extract from diff for `libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_set.h`)
>
> ```
>  +#if __cpp_deduction_guides >= 201606
>  +
>  +  template<typename _InputIterator,
>  +       typename _Compare =
>  +         less<typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::value_type>,
>  +       typename _Allocator =
>  +         allocator<typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::value_type>,
>  +       typename = _RequireInputIter<_InputIterator>,
>  +       typename = _RequireAllocator<_Allocator>>
>  +    set(_InputIterator, _InputIterator,
>  +    _Compare = _Compare(), _Allocator = _Allocator())
>  +    -> set<typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::value_type,
>  +      _Compare, _Allocator>;
>  +
>  +  template<typename _Key, typename _Compare = less<_Key>,
>  +       typename _Allocator = allocator<_Key>,
>  +       typename = _RequireAllocator<_Allocator>>
>  +    set(initializer_list<_Key>,
>  +    _Compare = _Compare(), _Allocator = _Allocator())
>  +    -> set<_Key, _Compare, _Allocator>;
>  +
>  +  template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Allocator,
>  +       typename = _RequireInputIter<_InputIterator>,
>  +       typename = _RequireAllocator<_Allocator>>
>  +    set(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Allocator)
>  +    -> set<typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::value_type,
>  +       less<typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::value_type>,
>  +       _Allocator>;
>  +
>  +  template<typename _Key, typename _Allocator,
>  +       typename = _RequireAllocator<_Allocator>>
>  +    set(initializer_list<_Key>, _Allocator)
>  +    -> set<_Key, less<_Key>, _Allocator>;
>  +
>  +#endif
> ```

This naturally explains why template argument deduction fails for the templated `set` by iterator(s) constructors for earlier versions of gcc, e.g. 7.2.0. If using the current gcc trunk (*gcc HEAD 8.0.0 20171103 (experimental)*) [the deduction guides above are available](https://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_set.h), and the template argument deduction is successful also for the iterator(s) constructors.

As for why the template argument deduction is successful already in gcc 7.2.0 for the `std::initializer_list` constructors (without deduction guides; guides that was also added in the commit above), as was somewhat explained in [@JohnZwinck deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47137602/4573247), these constructors are not templated themselves (not parameterized by their own template parameter list), but use `set`'s member type `value_type`—which is simply a typedef of the `set`'s first template type parameter `Key`—as template argument to the `std::initializer` list, which I would assume results in a simple enough deduction path to succeed even without and explicit deduction guide.